# How can i branch based on a columns value in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to have a dynamic `inner join..on` in an Oracle database.

For this purpose, I am getting the `table name`, and `User id` which acts as an access filter (return this person's records for example), and a `cursor` which returns the resulting dataTabe).

There is a slight problem here. The `userId` which is passed belongs to two different groups - buyers and sellers.  So, whenever I want to run my stored procedure and get the needed record I need to know if it's a buyer or a seller id, then have the correct condition applied in my `where` clause.

To cut it short, this is my half-complete query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.GET_DEAL_LIST 
  ( PersonID NUMBER,
    TableName NVARCHAR2,
    BuyerOrSeller INTEGER,
    a_CURSOR OUT sys_refcursor
  )
AS
BEGIN

  OPEN a_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TBLDEALS.*, TableName.* FROM TBLDEALS
      inner JOIN Tablename on 
      Tablename.ID = TBLDEALS.id
      --Now here I need a branch, something like this:
      --if (buyerOrSeller == 1 )//then this is a buyer
          and personID = TBLDEALS.Buyer_ID
      --else if (buyerOrSeller = 2 ) /then it is a seller and we need to return his record
          and PersonID = tblDeals.Seller_ID  


END;
/
```

For this I used `case` like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.GET_DEAL_LIST 
  ( PersonID NUMBER,
    TableName NVARCHAR2,
    BuyerOrSeller INTEGER,
    a_CURSOR OUT sys_refcursor
  )
AS
BEGIN

  OPEN a_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TBLDEALS.*,TableName.* FROM TBLDEALS
      inner JOIN Tablename on 
      Tablename.ID = TBLDEALS.id and
      case when BuyerOrSeller = 1 then TBLDEALS.Buyer_ID = PersonID
        when BuyerOrSeller = 2 then TBLDEALS.Buyer_ID = PersonID;
END;
/
```

But it seems to be wrong!( I get a

> Error(14,56): PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword

near equality sign in `TBLDEALS.Buyer_ID = PersonID`

And I am stuck on how to specify my `where` condition according to the `buyerOrSeller` variable.

Comment: With a variable table name, you have to use dynamic SQL anyway, so just build the right query. (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment, perhaps something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.GET_DEAL_LIST 
  ( PersonID NUMBER,
    TableName NVARCHAR2,
    BuyerOrSeller INTEGER,
    a_CURSOR OUT sys_refcursor
  )
AS
  v_stmt_str      VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  if BuyerOrSeller = 1 then
    v_stmt_str := 'SELECT TBLDEALS.*,t.* FROM TBLDEALS inner JOIN ' || tablename || ' t on t.ID = TBLDEALS.id and TBLDEALS.Buyer_ID = :PersonID)';
  else
    v_stmt_str := 'SELECT TBLDEALS.*,t.* FROM TBLDEALS inner JOIN ' || tablename || ' t on t.ID = TBLDEALS.id and TBLDEALS.Seller_ID = :PersonID)';
  end if;
  OPEN a_CURSOR FOR v_stmt_str using PersonID;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your *case statement* is the syntax is wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.GET_DEAL_LIST 
  ( PersonID NUMBER,
    TableName NVARCHAR2,
    BuyerOrSeller INTEGER,
    a_CURSOR OUT sys_refcursor
  )
AS
BEGIN

  OPEN a_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TBLDEALS.*,TableName.* FROM TBLDEALS
      inner JOIN Tablename on 
      Tablename.ID = TBLDEALS.id 
      and PersonID = (CASE BuyerOrSeller
                      WHEN 1 THEN TBLDEALS.Buyer_ID
                      WHEN 2 THEN TBLDEALS.Seller_ID
                      END);
END;
/
```

The above case statement would work, but the better solution is presented by teagles (as there are still problems with the rest of the query).